# grouping and sum with nested lists

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have nested lists and I'm trying to group and sum to get the desired result using java streams and collectors . With this I'm not able to loop over multiple `SubAccounts`. Either I have to use for loop or some other logic. I want to achieve using streams api. Is there any possibility for that

```
Map<Long, BigDecimal> assetQuanMap = subAccounts.getAssets.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Asset::getAssetId, Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Asset::getQuantity, BigDecimal::add)));
```

I'm having the below classes or representation :

```
    Account
        SubAccount1
            Assets
                1 - 20
                2 - 30
                3 - 40
        SubAccount2
            Assets
                1 - 10
                2 - 5
                3 - 3
        SubAccount3

                1 - 3
                2 - 3
                3 - 4
```

Accounts class looks like :

```
Public class Account{
  List<SubAccounts> list;
}

Public Class SubAccounts    {
   List<Assets> list;
}

Public class Assets{
    Long assetId;
    BigDecimal quantity ;
}
```

I'm trying to get the result as below in Map . Basically for each of the subAccounts i need to group the assets at account level which looks similar to below

```
1 - 33
2 - 38
3 - 47
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also could you format you question? It's a bit unreadable.

Comment: You're proably looking for flatMap.

Comment: what is `assetList` does it a List of Accounts or List of SubAccounts or what exactly

Comment: thank u, what i have tried is misleading that should be subAccounts. will edit to look more clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use two [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) so you can group by `assetId`

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> collect = accounts.stream()
        .flatMap(account -> account.getList().stream())
        .flatMap(subAccount -> subAccount.getList().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Assets::getAssetId,
                Collectors.reducing(
                        BigDecimal.ZERO, 
                        Assets::getQuantity,
                        BigDecimal::add)
        ));
```

from your code `assetId` is a String so the key of map should be a String, or you have to convert it, or change it in your class, like so :

```
Map<Long, BigDecimal> collect = accounts.stream()
        .flatMap(account -> account.getList().stream())
        .flatMap(subAccount -> subAccount.getList().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(asset -> Long.valueOf(asset.getAssetId()),
                Collectors.reducing(
                        BigDecimal.ZERO,
                        Assets::getQuantity,
                        BigDecimal::add
                )
        ));
```

---

**Notes**

- don't use plurals in the name of classes;
- don't name variable as `list`, use another significant name;
- don't use `assetId` as a name of attribute instead use just use `id`;
- don't use List in the name of variables `assetList`, instead use `s` in the end for example `assets` or `accounts`.

Comment: sorry i changed assetId to Long its mistake, and my grouping should start from subaccounts and to assetList. i understood a -> reprsents asset and s->represents subaccounts . Is this correct?

Comment: @sk27 I changed the names to make it more clear, check my edit and read the notes clearly please, hope this can help you

Comment: @sk27 I don't get you **and my grouping should start from subaccounts and to assetList** can you clarify please, what is the type of `assetList`

Comment: im not able to edit the post. Its not Accounts it is just Account and Account has SubAccounts and inside i have Assets. Basically Subaccounts and Assets are lists.

Comment: I don't get you @sk27 can you click to edit button to your question and add more details?

Comment: hi thank u and for your patience in answering ,im able to acheive with flatmap as you said in ur solution.