# Convert List into Map of Maps

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a list of objects with following fields:

```
public final UUID uuid;
public final LocalDate date;
public final long value;
```

and I want to convert it into the `Map<UUID, Map<LocalDate, Long>>` but at the same time I need to sum values by date.

So having data like this:

```
UUID | LocalDate | Long
uuid1| 2012-12-10| 100
uuid1| 2012-12-11| 200
uuid2| 2012-12-10| 300
uuid2| 2012-12-10| 200
```

I want to have:

```
uuid1: {
   [2012-12-10, 100],
   [2012-12-11, 200]
},
uuid2: {
   [2012-12-10, 500]
}
```

Is it possibe to achieve this using Stream API?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: if you have given some class structure and data, I would try. Just asking is it possible, then answer is it is always possible.

Comment: almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343820/grouping-and-sum-with-nested-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your class looks like this with setter and getters

```
public class SomeObject {
        public   UUID uuid;
        public  LocalDate date;
        public  Long value;
```

you can use the variant of `Collectors.groupingBy` which accepts a classifier function and another collector to group by uuid and and collect the object to map

```
Map<UUID, Map<LocalDate, Long>> collect = someObjects.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeObject::getUuid,
                        Collectors.toMap(SomeObject::getDate, SomeObject::getValue,Long::sum)));
```